# Add variables to header using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, header

Im trying to get an option value and add it to the header location.

```
<select id="time">
<option value="1"> 1 hour</option>
<option value="2"> 2 hours</option>
</select>
```

When an option is selected from the above list it should then add it as a get variable to the current header url.. such as

header=www.test.com?time=2

```
<select id="time2">
<option value="1"> 1 min</option>
<option value="2"> 2 min</option>
</select>
```

While current header being www.test.com?time=2
If a value was chosen from that list then min=2 should be added to the current header.
i.e - www.test.com?time=2&min=2

(there are multiple select options, so when each one is selected how can i add the get variable to the current header ?

```
$('time').on('change', function (e) 
{?
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
// binding an event-handler to the 'change' event (selecting by class-name):
$('.query').change(function(){
    // retrieving the current hash (though search is, of course, an alternative):
    var query = window.location.hash;
    /* if there is a current hash we apppend the name and value of the
       current select element to that hash:
    */
    window.location.hash = (query.length > 0 ? query + '&' : '') + this.name + this.value;
    // verifying the change/showing what was set/changed:
    console.log(window.location.hash);
/* triggering the change-handler function, this can be omitted if you don't
   want the handler to run on page-load: */
}).change();
```

Coupled with the slightly amended HTML:

```
<select name="hour" class="query">
    <option value="1"> 1 hour</option>
    <option value="2"> hours</option>
</select>

<select name="mins" class="query">
    <option value="1"> 1 min</option>
    <option value="2"> 2 min</option>
</select>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/39SNm/2/).

This updates the `window.location.hash` (`#time=2`), rather than the `window.location.search` (`?time=2`) because updating the latter will cause the page to reload (with the new search-string), whereas updating the `hash` prevents the page from reloading.

If, however, the page-reload isn't a problem for you, then you can simply use the `window.location.search` instead of the `window.location.hash`.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your reply.. it works ! how ever though it keeps on adding time=2, time=1,time=1 .. when i reselect the option.. is there a way where i can change the get value for time if it already exists in the location hash instead of appending it to the existing one ?